# Why does the java enhanced for loop give different results than the "traditional"?

Tags: java, foreach

I assumed that the enhanced for loop was just some syntactic sugar and behaves exactly like the "traditional" for loop. I prepared some code below which does indicate that this is not the case.
What is the reason for the different outputs? Or did I miss something and I should stop writing my code this way?

Why does t not refer to temp[(current index)]? For me it does not make sense that it does *not*

```
String temp[] = { "foo:bar" };
for (String t : temp)
    t = t.split(":", 2)[1];
System.out.println(temp[0].startsWith("foo")); //true
for (int t = 0; t < temp.length; t++)
    temp[t] = temp[t].split(":", 2)[1];
System.out.println(temp[0].startsWith("foo")); //false
```

Comment: In the second example you change the `temp` variable.

Comment: I assumed that t refers to temp[i]

Comment: @user2084795: No, Java doesn't do variable references, not even in the enhanced for loop. `t` is just a temporary variable, it's nothing special. The enhanced for loop is basically: `for (int i = 0; i < temp; ++i) { String t= temp[i]; /* ...your code...*/ }` [Details in the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2).

Comment: `temp[i]` refers to `item`.

Comment: No, it doesn't. If you use the enhanced for loop, you can't use indices or modify the list in any way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The foreach loop is in fact equivalent to

```
for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++)
    String t = temp[i];
    t = t.split(":", 2)[1];
}
```

which doesn't change any element of the array.

Comment: [Details in the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2)

Comment: Is there any way to modify my for loops to give the same result?

Comment: If you want to modify the array, then use the traditional loop. The foreach loop is designed to access each element in the array. Not to modify it.

Comment: @user2084795: That said, you *could* do this: `int i = 0; for (String t : temp) { temp[i++] = t.split(":", 2)[1]; }`. I wouldn't recommend it, as JB says just use a traditional loop, but you *can*.

Answer (score 3):

You are not testing the same string with the two tests.

When you first execute the test, the string is (still) `"foo:bar"` - your first loop doesn't change the string, it only changes the loop variable `t`.

But this line:

```
temp[t] = temp[t].split(":", 2)[1];
```

overwrites the string `"foo:bar"` with the second element after splitting it on a colon, namely `"bar"`, which doesn't start with `"foo"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int t = 0; t < temp.length; t++)
        {
            temp[t] = temp[t].split(":", 2)[1];
            System.out.println(temp[t]);
        }
```

This prints "bar" which means the value "foo" is being overwritten inside the `for` loop.
So, the final result it false.